# Read Data from PCB board Through a Serial Cable with java

Tags: java, rxtx

Using eclipse and java how to read the data from the pcb board with a serial cable, because the data of the pcb board arrive via cable in binary format. How to save the data that will be displayed in the compiler?
Someone help me please.

Below is the code I am writing to do this, but it does not detect any port when I plug in the serial cable

```
import gnu.io.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.TooManyListenersException;


public class SimpleRead implements Runnable, SerialPortEventListener {
    static CommPortIdentifier portId;
    static Enumeration        portList;
    InputStream           inputStream;
    SerialPort            serialPort;
    Thread            readThread;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean           portFound = false;
    String            defaultPort ="COM 1" ;

    if (args.length > 0) {
        defaultPort = args[0];
    } 

    portList = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();

    while (portList.hasMoreElements()) {
        portId = (CommPortIdentifier) portList.nextElement();
        if (portId.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL) {
        if (portId.getName().equals(defaultPort)) {
            System.out.println("Found port: "+defaultPort);
            portFound = true;
            SimpleRead reader = new SimpleRead();
        } 
        } 
    } 
    if (!portFound) {
        System.out.println("port " + defaultPort + " not found.");
    } 

    } 


    public SimpleRead() {
    try {
        serialPort = (SerialPort) portId.open("SimpleReadApp", 2000);
    } catch (PortInUseException e) {}

    try {
        inputStream = serialPort.getInputStream();
    } catch (IOException e) {}

    try {
        serialPort.addEventListener(this);
    } catch (TooManyListenersException e) {}

    serialPort.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);

    try {
        serialPort.setSerialPortParams(9600, SerialPort.DATABITS_8, 
                       SerialPort.STOPBITS_1, 
                       SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
    } catch (UnsupportedCommOperationException e) {}

    readThread = new Thread(this);

    readThread.start();
    }


    public void run() {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(20000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    } 


    public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) {
    switch (event.getEventType()) {

    case SerialPortEvent.BI:

    case SerialPortEvent.OE:

    case SerialPortEvent.FE:

    case SerialPortEvent.PE:

    case SerialPortEvent.CD:

    case SerialPortEvent.CTS:

    case SerialPortEvent.DSR:

    case SerialPortEvent.RI:

    case SerialPortEvent.OUTPUT_BUFFER_EMPTY:
        break;

    case SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE:
        byte[] readBuffer = new byte[20];

        try {
        while (inputStream.available() > 0) 
        {
            int numBytes = inputStream.read(readBuffer);
            System.out.print("The Read Bytes from SerialPort are");
            System.out.write(readBuffer);
            System.out.println();
        } 

        System.out.print(new String(readBuffer));
        } catch (IOException e) {}

        break;
    }
    } 

}
```

Log Result:

port COM 1 not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The port names don't have spaces in them. Try changing:

```
String            defaultPort ="COM 1" ;
```

to:

```
String            defaultPort ="COM1" ;
```

Comment: Thanks for that answer, i just change "COM 1" to "COM5" and now i see connected the serial port but i cannot read bytes